# Making the height of list items in a row follow their largest height

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

In this page:
http://pastehtml.com/view/1biylhs.html

You can see the book in the center needs more height space than the other two books in the same row because its title has more text.

Currently, each book is contained in a `<li>` and has a height of 175px.

I can set their height to auto but it still can't make all list items in the same row follow the largest height among them:

http://pastehtml.com/view/1bj19w3.html

What is the simplest way to make the list items in each row follow the largest height of those list items in that row? I have to make it work in IE6 as well.

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: personally, if it is tabulated info, i'd still use a table

Comment: I think you should be able to make this work if you use a combination of a container and floats / clears. I am only on a 5 minute break right now though so cant demo it. Will come back later and try to work out a solution.

Comment: As stated above, if you use tabular data, use tables. I found that trying to use CSS pyrotechnics can be gratifying but too time consuming.

Comment: @Mic this is not tabular data.  You could say the book image and title can be displayed as a table, but this is pure layout.

Comment: @joeri, I meant tabular layout

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy I can do it in the way you suggest but using a <div> to contain each row would mean there will be lots of separated <ul>s, which may look unfriendly to search engines (this is just my guess).

Comment: @bobo I dont know how else you could achieve what you want. I know using floats and clears would be the way I would do it. My guess is you would use a div, a ul with float: left and a div after the ul (within the container) with clear: both. I havent tested this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding some additional markup. Make it a list of lists perhaps.

Something like this

```
<ul>
 <li class="row">
  <ul>
   <li class="book">
    <img />
    <h2>title</h2>
   </li>
   <li class="book">
    <img />
    <h2>title</h2>
   </li>
   <li class="book">
    <img />
    <h2>title</h2>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<!-- repeat rows here--></ul>
```

Then some CSS along the lines of

.row{
  clear:left;
  float:left;
  min-height:175px;
}

Note the min-height which allows the height to expand. You will need to feed height to IE6 to achieve the same effect. To do that, you have a lot of options. [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) are one of the standards-compliant choices.

Finally, note that I have used h2 instead of div to contain the book titles. You probably want to give the titles a bit of semantic weight to make them stand out to searches, and so h2 (or any header element) is a better container than div.

Answer (score 2):

I handle it with Javascript:

```
function resizerows(classname) { 
    //init some vars
    var tablerowlist = new Array();
    var maxheight=0;

    //get all elements with same class
    var rowlist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    //loop through items and check class name
    for (var r=0; r<rowlist.length; r++) { 
        if (rowlist[r].className.indexOf(classname) != -1) {
            //if class name contains classname this is an li we are looking for, add to our array
            tablerowlist.push(rowlist[r]);
        }//end class name check
    }//end loop through all the li elements

    //loop through our good list of li elements
    for(var l=0; l<tablerowlist.length; l++) {
        //dig through the li tag and get all the elements 
        var childlist = tablerowlist[l].children;

        //init a max height

        //loop through the child elements (in this case <p> tags)
        for(var c=0; c<childlist.length; c++) { 
            //check to make sure its a P tag
            if (childlist[c].tagName == "P") { 
                //compare height of element to maxheight, if greater maxheight = element height
                if (childlist[c].offsetHeight > maxheight) { 
                    maxheight = childlist[c].offsetHeight; 
                }
            }
        }//end loop through child elements

        //now we have the maxheight loop through all the rows and set the height to max height
        for (var ch=0; ch<childlist.length; ch++) {
            childlist[ch].style.height = (maxheight)  + "px";
        }

        //reset max height;
        maxheight = 0;
    }//end loop through the li elements
}
```

It's a little blunt, you can get more elegant code using a framework like jquery but this has worked for me, cross browser and platform.

Edit:

This is for HTML code formatted thus:

```
<ul>
<li class="row">
    <p class="item">Item 1</p>
    <p class="item">Item 2</p>
    <p class="item">Item 3, which is really really long text that'll be bigger than the other two items</p>
</li>

<li class="row">
    <p class="item">Item 1</p>
    <p class="item">Item 2</p>
    <p class="item">Item 3, which is really really long text that'll be bigger than the other two items</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Each row may have its own max height and that's the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not easy to do.  You talk about rows, but the browser is not seeing rows, it's just seeing wrapped floats.

You could go for tables (not because it's tabular, but just because this layout is very difficult to do without any) but I wouldn't give up that quickly.

As a compromise, I would suggest making each floated block high enough for the image and about three lines of text.   Then they each have the same height and line up nicely It's still a guess, but probably the best you can do. .

Comment: This won't work when you have four lines of text, of course, or if someone increases the font size

Comment: Joeri makes sense. Calculate the vertical space for the worst-case scenario, and the apply that height to all items.

Comment: This is not really a good idea, if the worse case is 7 lines of text and this worse case does not appear often. Setting a worse case fixed height to all list items will leave too much height space, which looks strange, for most of the time.